# Detailed example for uninitializedEntityFilter

Tags: drools, optaplanner

I have set my planning variable to be nullable. But using this the construction heuristic initializes variables to null values and i think this is a waste of time for computing the optimal solution. From the documents you can overwrite this using uninitializedEntityFilter. But it doesnt show the actual UninitializedTaskFilter.class. What would be the content of this class? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If `nullable=true`, you probably want to have score constraints that inflict a penalty for that, so OptaPlanner avoids setting the variable to `null`.

The only difference with `nullable=false` is that it's not a build-in hard constraint, because in some cases - such as overconstrained planning - it's better to leave it null than to initialize it somewhere where it's conflicting with another allocation.

Another use case to have variables on null is if you multiple variables and some variables are not applicable in some cases. But generally, subclassing is a better approach there (and now supported in 6)

To answer your question: `SelectionFilter`.
Note: `uninitializedEntityFilter` has been renamed to `reinitializeVariableEntityFilter` in 6.0.0.Alpha7 to better reflect it's usage (and the documentation has been clarified too). I strongly suggest to update to the latest and greatest version 6.0.0.CR5 (just follow the upgrade recipe) as it has many improvements/bugfixes related to `nullable` etc.

From it's javadoc:

```
/**
 * Construction heuristics only change reinitializable planning variables.
 * Non reinitializable planning variable is ignored by construction heuristics.
 * This is especially useful in repeated planning use cases,
 * in which starting from scratch would waste previous results and time.
 * <p/>
 * If no {@link #reinitializeVariableEntityFilter} is specified,
 * the default considers an entity uninitialized for a variable if its value is null
 * (even if {@link #nullable()} is true).
 * <p/>
 * The method {@link SelectionFilter#accept(ScoreDirector, Object)}
 * returns false if the selection entity should be reinitialized for this variable
 * and it returns true if the selection entity should not be reinitialized for this variable
 * @return {@link NullReinitializeVariableEntityFilter} when it is null (workaround for annotation limitation)
 */
Class<? extends SelectionFilter> reinitializeVariableEntityFilter()
        default NullReinitializeVariableEntityFilter.class;
```